# Select Distinct Values from different columns MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having trouble with this.
I have a mysql table with the following columns:

[MySQL columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw5wc.png)

This Table has more than the shown on the picture, however i just need to fetch data from the ones that are shown in the picture.

The columns contain tag words and they are repeated often.
I need to grab a single array containing the Tags without getting the duplicate entries but getting all the unique ones.

How can i do this?
What would be the best query for this purpose?

Also, if possible i would like to count the number of times that this tag appears on the table.

I intend to display the data on a PHP while() loop like this:

TagA (#videos)
TagB (#videos)
[...]

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be storing the tags in separate columns like that.  Instead, they should be in a table with one row per video and on per tag.

Given this structure, you can do what you want with `union all`:

```
select tag, count(*)
from (select tag1 as tag from t union all
      select tag2 as tag from t union all
      select tag3 as tag from t union all
      select tag4 as tag from t union all
      select tag5 as tag from t
     ) t
group by tag;
```

Comment: I know i shouldn't be doing it like this, but its functional, its enough and it will be processed more quickly because its one less query to deal with

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, all tag words from any column are treated equally, so a union of all counts by each tag field should work.

```
select tag, sum(tagCount) as tagCount from
(select tag1 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag1
UNION
select tag2 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag2
UNION
select tag3 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag3
UNION
select tag4 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag4
UNION
select tag5 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag5)
GROUP BY tag
```

Caveat: I don't have a DB connection in front of me to try this out immediately.

Comment: Haven't tested yet, i'll do in about 15minutes.
Sounds very logic your soulution, 
I will be able to fetch it as `$var['tag']` and `$varTotal['tagCount']` if i got your idea correctly, right?

Comment: `<?php
include("includes/dbconnect.php");
$getTagsQuery = mysql_query("
select tag, sum(tagCount) from
(select tag1 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag1
UNION
select tag2 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag2
UNION
select tag3 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag3
UNION
select tag4 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag4
UNION
select tag5 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag5)
GROUP BY tag
");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getTagsQuery)){
 echo "
  ".$row['tag']."
  ";
}
?>` Not Working

Comment: You might have to change the first line "sum(tagCount)" aggregate field to "sum(tagCount) as tagCount" in the first line, but yes I believe so.

Comment: `include("includes/dbconnect.php");
$getTagsQuery = mysql_query("
select tag, sum(tagCount as tagCount) from
(select tag1 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag1
UNION
select tag2 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag2
UNION
select tag3 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag3
UNION
select tag4 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag4
UNION
select tag5 as tag, count(*) as tagCount from yourTable GROUP BY tag5)
GROUP BY tag
");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getTagsQuery)){
 echo "
  ".$row['tag']."
  ";
}`